# How to find the parent object from the child(property) object in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a situation where the child to be able to reference the parent. The reason for this is that I want the child to have the ability to update the parent object.

configuration.Range.Next(configuration)

I do not want to pass the parent object reference instead the Range object should be able to find its parent object. How would I do this?

> Class Range { ....MethodX(){How do I access the Configuration Object here } }
>
> Class Configuration { public Range range{get;set;} ..... }

Comment: I imagine the ideal approach is to hold a reference to the parent.  Can you show your object structure?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the difficulty with answering your question is that people use the terms "child" and "parent" to mean different things to different people.

One of the most common uses of the terms is as synonyms for subclass (child) and superclass (parent) in an inheritance structure. Assuming that is your meaning, you already have access to anything from the superclass (i.e. "parent") that is declared as `public` or `protected`. For example:

```
public class Parent
{
    protected int Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Foo = 42;
        // or
        base.Foo = 42;
    }
}
```

If this isn't the situation you're working with please add more information to your original question to better describe what you mean when you use the terms "child" and "parent."